# Passing a parameter to a 'new' action via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Rails newbie here and I'm stumped.  In Rails I have a Project Model which has_many Tasks.  Lets say I have a view that is displaying 5 projects and each project has a 'New Task' link so that the user can add a new task to any one of the projects.  So:

Project 1 
New Task

Project 2 
New Task 
etc.

If the New Task link looks like

link_to 'New Task', new_task_path

what is the best way to tell the 'new' action on the tasks controller which link was clicked?  I figure I have to pass the project_id to the new task, but I can't solve out how to do it.

Help appreciated as always!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends how your routes are defined, but if tasks are defined as a subresource of a project (such as the following) then it's pretty simple.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

This will generate routes such as:

```
new_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)                         {:controller=>"tasks", :action=>"new"}
```

And then you can link to it via:

```
link_to 'New Task', new_project_task_path(@project)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.  Seems I have to login to up-vote you for this answer.  Will do tomorrow.

Comment: @Ben it's not necessary to do this: `new_project_task_path(:project_id => @project.id)`. You can just pass in the instance and Rails handles the rest: `new_project_task_path(@project)`.